Error running .NET 6.0 project after upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.9.6
I recently upgraded my development environment from Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.8.3 to Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.9.6. After the upgrade, I encountered the following error when attempting to run my .NET 6.0 project:
T**his exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal, object, string)
    MeerkatSafeSchoolEN.WebApp.Filter.MultiplePolicysAuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext) in PoliciesAuthorizationHandler.cs
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync.__Awaited|20_0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker, System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope, object, bool) in ResourceInvoker.cs
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync.__Awaited|17_0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker, System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.IDisposable) in ResourceInvoker.cs
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync.__Awaited|17_0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker, System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.IDisposable) in ResourceInvoker.cs
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke.__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Endpoint, System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger) in EndpointMiddleware.cs
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext) in AuthorizationMiddleware.cs
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext) in AuthenticationMiddleware.cs
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext) in SessionMiddleware.cs**

Additionally, I noticed that the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy  version 2.2.0 is deprecated. However, when I try to update it, Visual Studio prompts me to update the project to .NET 8, which I would prefer to avoid at this time. Rolling back to Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.8.3 resolves the issue, but I would like to find a solution without updating to .NET 8.
Are there any known compatibility issues or workarounds specific to Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.9.6 that might help resolve this error and the deprecated NuGet package issue without updating to .NET 8?
I expected that upgrading Visual Studio would not cause any compatibility issues with my .NET 6.0 project and that I would be able to resolve the deprecated NuGet package without being forced to update to .NET 8.

do you have any specific reasoning behind not upgrading to .NET 8 at once and sticking to .NET 6? both are LTS.

a lot of libraries are being phased out in .NET, which is the issue here. what was the SDK version of the original project before you upgraded to 6?

The project is currently live on .NET 6 in production. As we are in the process of revamping the project, we require a temporary solution for the next few months. Therefore, sticking with .NET 6 aligns with our immediate needs.

Before the upgrade to .NET 6, the original project was using SDK versions ranging from .NET 3 to 5

Visual Studio has nothing to do with the .NET version used. You'd get the same compiler warnings and errors if you tried to build and run the project from the command line. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy was deprecated when .NET 6.0 was released, not now.

I just found that the package was deprecated in .NET 3. You're lucky things worked as long as they did. This is explicitly mentioned in the 2.2 to 3.0 migration guide. Check the other migration guides and the Use ASP.NET Core APIs in a class library
